# IBM Cloudant/PouchDB replication issue, status:400, bad_request

Tags: angular, typescript, replication, pouchdb, cloudant

Having an error with a remote IBM Cloudant database replication. 
I'm using "pouchdb": "^7.2.1" in an Angular 8 app with TypeScript.
The weirdest thing is that sometimes it works and sometimes not.
When it's not, it says:

```
CustomPouchError {error: "bad_request", reason: "Please supply either IAM session cookie or basic auth not both", status: 400, name: "bad_request", message: "Please supply either IAM session cookie or basic auth not both", …}
error: "bad_request"
reason: "Please supply either IAM session cookie or basic auth not both"
status: 400
name: "bad_request"
...
```

The code used to replicate from remote DB is straight forward:

```
private startReplication(localDB: PouchDB.Database, remoteDB: PouchDB.Database):Promise<PouchDB.Database> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let replicationHandler = localDB.replicate
        .from(remoteDB, {
          batch_size: 200,
          batches_limit: 10
        })
        .on("paused", info => {
          replicationHandler.cancel()
        })
        .on("complete", info => {
          replicationHandler.cancel()
          resolve()
        })
        .on("error", err => {
          replicationHandler.cancel()
          reject(err)
        })
    })
  }
```

Remote DB is defined like this:

```
let userDB = "https://token:password@myurl.cloudant.com/mydatabase$username"
this.remoteDB = new PouchDB(`${userDB}`, {
      auto_compaction: true
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the Cloudant server thinks you're making a request using both basic auth *and* an IAM session cookie, which it rejects. Maybe try clearing your Cloudant cookies?